# handling multiple input in a array of objects

Tags: reactjs, axios, react-hooks, material-ui

I am trying to handle multiple inputs in a array of objects and each object I am mapping to the input field in a form .Now I am getting empty array I want to know where I am doing wrong .I am also sending post axios request and the value I am getting in input text fields through urlParmas using hooks.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";
import axios from "axios";
import { Button, TextField } from "@material-ui/core";

const MyComponent = () => {
  const [sale, setSale] = useState("");
  const [district, setDistrict] = useState("");
  const obj = [
    {
      key: 1,
      label: "Sales office",
      handleChange: (e) => {
        setSale(e.target.value);
      },
      val: sale,
    },
    {
      key: 2,
      label: "Sales district",
      handleChange: (e) => {
        setDistrict(e.target.value);
      },
      val: sale,
    },
  ];
  const [object, setObject] = useState(obj);
  const handleSubmit = () => {
    axios
      .post("localhots:8000", {
        sale,
        district,
      })
      .then(() => {});
    setSale("");
    setDistrict("");
  };

  const handleComment = (e, item) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    let result = object;
    result = result.map((el) => {
      if (el.name === item.name) el.name = e.target.value;
      return el;
    });
    console.log(result);
    setObject(result);
  };
  const { search } = useLocation();
  const urlParams = Object.fromEntries([...new URLSearchParams(search)]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const { salesoff } = urlParams;
    setSale(salesoff);
  }, []);

  object.map((item, index) => {
    return (
      <div>
        <form
          onSubmit={(e) => {
            e.target.reset();
          }}
        >
          <TextField
            name={item.name}
            value={item.sale}
            label={item.label}
            onChange={handleChange}
            
          />
          <Button
            type="submit"
            fullWidth
            variant="contained"
            color="primary"
            onClick={() => handleSubmit()}
          >
            Submit
          </Button>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  });
};

export default MyComponent;
```

Comment: Where are you getting an empty array.  Also why do you have a form for each input field and why don't you use the handleChange function provided within each item

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri now I am not getting empty array but the only issue is after mapping the objects into form its not working also I have used handleChange function with each item